# Deserializing DateTime format not working for Tues abbreviation

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following JSON request... From the third party.

```
{
    "show_time": "Tues 28/08/2018 18:00",
    "end_time": "28/08/2018 07:55:00 PM",
}
```

And, in the DTOs class, I have the following date time converter.

```
[Required]
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "show_time")]
[JsonConverter(typeof(DateTimeFormatConverter), "ddd dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")]
public DateTime ShowTime { get; set; }
```

And, custom JsonConverter class.

```
public class DateTimeFormatConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public DateTimeFormatConverter(string format)
    {
        DateTimeFormat = format;
    }
}
```

But I got this error...

```
FormatException: String 'Tues 28/08/2018 18:00' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(ReadOnlySpan<char> s, ReadOnlySpan<char> format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)
```

What should I do, others abbreviation date is work as expected (ex. Mon, Wed).

**Ref.**

source of my DateTime format "ddd dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1

Comment: `Tues` isn't a normal abbreviation - it should be `Tue`.

Comment: If you can't change serialization part, just do not consider weekday (first) part (you don't need it anyway).

Comment: @John but it the Ref. link in my question shown that it's possible. And this data comes from the third-party. is there a way I can deal with it?

Comment: Given that's not official documentation, I suspect it's a typo. [Official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.abbreviateddaynames?view=netframework-4.8). Personally, I'd create a converter that splits off the first part and only uses the `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm` part.

Comment: @John would you mind to show me a converter that splits off the first part.

Comment: @JongzPuangput There is no such converter, just get your date json into `string`, cut out the first part, and parse/assign it to `DateTime` property.

Comment: [Here is the IsoDateTimeConverter source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/IsoDateTimeConverter.cs) as a starting point. I'd probably just split into 2 strings on space, and then ignore the first half.

Comment: At first, I try to change the abbreviation by using this method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.abbreviateddaynames?view=netcore-2.2 at Main application but it seems not working also. I'll try your approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following approach since the entire application will have to deal with these kinds of date both input and output from/to a third-party system.

in the Startup.cs

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Web API Culture Configuration
            RequestCulture rc = new RequestCulture("en-US");
            CultureInfo ci = rc.Culture;
            DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = ci.DateTimeFormat;
            dtfi.AbbreviatedDayNames = new String[] { "Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat" };
            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultRequestCulture = rc;
            });

            // Other configurations
            ....
            ....
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {

            app.UseRequestLocalization();

            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

Thank you for all the comments below the question.